# Getting trapped, and passing to self off of your opponent's backboard/rim?

Tags: basketball, nba

So, we see how Kobe Bryant is able to hit the ball off his backboard (after getting trapped), and easily score as he catches it right under the hoop.

What if you're trapped backcourt (under your opponent's basket). Can you hit the ball of off your opponent's backboard, catch it, and continue dribbling down the court?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The accepted answer is wrong or perhaps just confusing.   Read this [article](http://www.espn.com/blog/truehoop/post/_/id/26902/legalized-passing-to-yourself) to get the rule breakdown.   You can pass to yourself off of your backboard or rim, however you cannot do so on your opponent's rim.    As noted in the comments on the other answer Ricky Davis's pass was called a violation by Sloan and Sloan is right.

First Ricky Davis traveled - because he caught the ball with two hands after the "shot attempt".   He could have pushed the ball against the rim and continued dribbling.   That being said you can push the ball 50 feet in the air and continue dribbling.   Ricky Davis caught the ball with two hands so he was not continuing a dribble, he was starting one, which is a very very clear travel.

So yes for your rim, backboard, and a big no to your opponent's.

(side note and nothing to do with the question but Ricky Davis also should have had a tech for shooting on purpose on the opponent's basket - which is a tech example in rulebook revisions)

Answer (score 0):

That should work. I recall one NBA player who tried a rebound against the own board during the last minute of a game, as this would have been the 10th rebound, yielding a triple double. Despite being silly (in that case), this is perfectly legal. I rather wonder whether the opponents might not be allowed to stay that long beneath the basket (three second rule).

Comment: Oh, Ricky Davis lol. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XDtGHHnA9ms. Jerry Sloan did say that it was a "violation" though (1:59), and we know the NBA only loosely enforce rules (traveling, punching the ball, etc.).

Comment: thanks for the link. Apparently (https://www.basketball-reference.com/boxscores/pbp/200303160CLE.html) the rebound was not attributed to Davis. On the other hand, it was not called a foul.